# Fragment OnStop() Called when the Fragment is no longer started?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am confused with the documentation for fragments

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStop()
>
> Called when the Fragment is no longer started.

As much i know if User navigates backward or fragment is replaced/removed `onStop()` is called.

Can anyone explain me how `onStop()` is called when the fragment is no longer started?

Comment: I'll try to put this politely - some of the people who document Android code basically do it very badly. I suggest you scroll up the documentation for `Fragment` to the "Lifecycle" section which gives a slightly better explanation - "onStop() fragment is no longer visible to the user either because its activity is being stopped or a fragment operation is modifying it in the activity". Similar to an `Activity`, when it is no longer visible to the user, a `Fragment` will be 'stopped' and, at this point, its `onStop()` method is called.

Comment: @Squonk i understood this but you mean to say they have poorly documented this without enough description

Comment: In general the documentation is OK but there's a lot of it and it's not unusual for me to come across Android documentation which has no description, incomplete description or is misleading. Your question is a prime example of this - saying "...is no longer started" is grammatically incorrect and makes very little sense. It should actually say "Called when the Fragment is stopped."